# How to get the original variable name from a list of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of pandas data frames and want to iterate over it and get the original variable names. I've tried the following but print line throws an error ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'):

```
import pandas as pd

testFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["test1"])
testFrame2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["test2"])

listOfFrames = [testFrame1,testFrame2]

for frame in listOfFrames:
    print(frame.name) #<--This throws an error
```

In this case I would like the output to be:
testFrame1
testFrame2

Background:
I have a function that takes in dataframes and appends each of them to an Excel file with a new sheet. It works but each new sheet is being named "Analysis_0", "Analysis_1", etc. I would prefer to have each new sheet named after the data frame variable (in this case "testFrame1", "testFrame2", etc). Here's the function so far:

```
def addDFWorksheetToExcelFile(excelFile,*dataFrames):
    # copied from stackoverflow
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    book = load_workbook(excelFile)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(excelFile, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        ## Your dataframes to append.
        frameNo = 0
        for dataFrame in dataFrames:
            # This is where I would like to name the Excel sheet after the original data frame variable name
            dataFrame.to_excel(writer, "Analysis_" + str(frameNo)) 
            frameNo += 1
        writer.save()
    # end copy stackoverflow
```

Comment: where does the list of dataframes come from?

Comment: Can you provide more context? It sounds like you'd prefer to store your dataframes in a dictionary. With information you provided, I can think of any way that knowing the variable names is helpful

Comment: Values don't have any backward reference to the variables that hold them. There's no way to get the variable name from a value, other than searching the `globals()` and `locals()` array for it.

Comment: This seems like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382) to me. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Hi @PaulH, I've added the function I want to feed the data frames into for clarification. Hope that explains what I want to do and how I started wondering if there's any way to find out the original variable names from within a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually set a name method for your dataframes.

```
testFrame1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["test1"])
testFrame1.name = 'testFrame1'
testFrame2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["test2"])
testFrame2.name = 'testFrame2'

listOfFrames = [testFrame1,testFrame2]

for frame in listOfFrames:
    print(frame.name)
```

This will print the dataframe names